# .Net Core 3.1 importing WSDL Errors - How to work around?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, soap, wsdl

I am trying to migrate some server code from .Net 4.7 to .Net Core 3.1 so we can run on a Linux host.

There are two connected services using SOAP. One has ported with zero changes but other has errors when importing using the WSDL file:

> http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk/SOAP/IndividualService.php?wsdl

I'm not a SOAP expert and have only ever used the code generated by importing WSDL files so the errors don't mean a lot to me.

> Cannot import wsdl:port
> Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
> XPath to wsdl:binding: wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk']/wsdl:binding[@name='IndividualServiceHttpPost']
> XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk']/wsdl:service[@name='IndividualService']/wsdl:port[@name='IndividualServiceHttpPost']
> Cannot import wsdl:binding
> Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
> XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk']/wsdl:binding[@name='IndividualServiceHttpPost']
> Cannot import wsdl:port
> Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
> XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk']/wsdl:binding[@name='IndividualServiceHttpGet']
> XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk']/wsdl:service[@name='IndividualService']/wsdl:port[@name='IndividualServiceHttpGet']
> Cannot import wsdl:binding
> Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
> XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk']/wsdl:binding[@name='IndividualServiceHttpGet']

To simplify debugging I created simple command line apps, one for .Net 4.7 and the other Core 3.1.

Importing worked perfectly for the .Net 4.7 and I can call the service (as expected).

Importing for Core 3.1 gives the errors as above and when calling the client initialization it returns  an error of:

> Client.Channel = 'Client.Channel' threw an exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException'

I get the same errors when importing using svcutil.exe manually.

After 3 days Googling I am no further on as each problem seems to be different and none of the solutions work.

Would someone be kind enough to explain what these errors actually mean (I'm not a SOAP expert) and, if possible, what I sort of things I need to do to work around them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016709/the-required-wsdl-extension-element-binding-from-namespace)

Comment: @Gusman Thanks for the suggestion, but my code has no XHttpBinding that appears to be the solution for them.

Comment: No, but your problem is the same, various bindings that aren't supported by .net core, ex: `/wsdl:binding[@name='IndividualServiceHttpGet']`

Comment: So these should be removed from the WSDL before trying to import?  I'm a novice with WSDL so not exactly sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the WSDL to a file and remove the unsupported GET and POST bindings manually by removing the corresponding `wsdl:binding` and `wsdl:port` elements. You can then use the tools (`dotnet-svcutil` or Visual Studio / IDEs) to generate the client code (Service Reference).

```
    --- a/service.wsdl
    +++ b/service.wsdl
    @@ -286,37 +286,6 @@
           </wsdl:output>
         </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>
    -  <wsdl:binding name="IndividualServiceHttpGet" type="tns:IndividualServiceHttpGet">
    -    <http:binding verb="GET" />
    -    <wsdl:operation name="SearchByLastNameAndDateOfBirth">
    -      <http:operation location="/SearchByLastNameAndDateOfBirth" />
    -      <wsdl:input>
    -        <http:urlEncoded />
    -      </wsdl:input>
    -      <wsdl:output>
    -        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
    -      </wsdl:output>
    -    </wsdl:operation>
    -    <wsdl:operation name="SearchByDrivingLicenceNumber">
    -      <http:operation location="/SearchByDrivingLicenceNumber" />
    -      <wsdl:input>
    -        <http:urlEncoded />
    -      </wsdl:input>
    -      <wsdl:output>
    -        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
    -      </wsdl:output>
    -    </wsdl:operation>
    -    <wsdl:operation name="Get">
    -      <http:operation location="/Get" />
    -      <wsdl:input>
    -        <http:urlEncoded />
    -      </wsdl:input>
    -      <wsdl:output>
    -        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
    -      </wsdl:output>
    -    </wsdl:operation>
    -  </wsdl:binding>
    -  <wsdl:binding name="IndividualServiceHttpPost" type="tns:IndividualServiceHttpPost">
         <http:binding verb="POST" />
         <wsdl:operation name="SearchByLastNameAndDateOfBirth">
           <http:operation location="/SearchByLastNameAndDateOfBirth" />
    @@ -354,11 +323,5 @@
         <wsdl:port name="IndividualServiceSoap12" binding="tns:IndividualServiceSoap12">
           <soap12:address location="http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk/SOAP/IndividualService.php" />
         </wsdl:port>
    -    <wsdl:port name="IndividualServiceHttpGet" binding="tns:IndividualServiceHttpGet">
    -      <http:address location="http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk/SOAP/IndividualService.php" />
    -    </wsdl:port>
    -    <wsdl:port name="IndividualServiceHttpPost" binding="tns:IndividualServiceHttpPost">
    -      <http:address location="http://uat.risc.enexusrental.co.uk/SOAP/IndividualService.php" />
    -    </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>
     </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer. I had eventually figured this out myself by editing the downloaded WSDL file and it is now working. What held me up for a while was VS wasn't refreshing the file once edited and I had to keep renaming to a new file after each test edit. I had come back to add this answer myself to let others know what to do (as so many seem to be struggling), but seeing as you answered it already I'll just mark yours as correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem afterwards I utilize "svcutil" and created a batch file with below command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\svcutil.exe" <your service address/url like http://localhost:*****/***/**/***** >  /o:"<name of class file to be created>.cs" /r:"..\..\<Any reference assembly if any otherwise leave this>" /n:*,<targetNamespace>  /ct:<collectionType:<type> like System.Collections.Generic.List`1>
```

for more information on svcutil go to dev command of VS and run command: svcutil/?