# Remove wrapped tag from manual wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

i'm spending too much days to resolve an issue with SOAP :(
I have to recreate a SOAP endpoint in .Net Core with CoreWCF based on wsdl used from the client (my project is an upgrade of an old .net 4.7 application) so i need to respect the old wsdl. Unfortunately i cannot to import on VS the old wsdl because i have to implement CoreWCF instead ServiceModel and prepopulated reference are on ServiceModel, also if i change the references the input parameter on the OperationContract is always null.
So i try to define manually Service Contract, Operation Contract, Data Member and so on.

This is the xml structure that client sends me.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.me/method/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:method1>
            <msgContBody>
                <par1>Hello</par1>
                <descPar1>Desc of Hello</descPar1>
                <par2>World</par2>
                <descPar2>Desc of World</descPar2>
                <arrayPar>
                    <Id>1</Id>
                    <Desc>one</Desc>
                </arrayPar>
                <arrayPar>
                    <Id>2</Id>
                    <Desc>two</Desc>
                </arrayPar>
                <arrayPar>
                    <Id>3</Id>
                    <Desc>three</Desc>
                </arrayPar>
            </msgContBody>
        </ns1:method1>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The method is just one and wsdl define a MessageContract with a MessageContractBody that contains just an array.
When i try to recreate the endpoint i have 2 nested object instead of one and again i have to reference the namespace just for the first tag.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.me/method/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:method1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns1:request>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <rootPar>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <par1>?</par1>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <descPar1>?</descPar1>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <par2>?</par2>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <descPar2>?</descPar2>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <arrayPar>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                    <arrayPar>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <Id>1</Id>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <Desc>one</Desc>
                    </arrayPar>
                    <arrayPar>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <Id>2</Id>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <Desc>two</Desc>
                    </arrayPar>
                    <arrayPar>
                        <!--Optional:--
                        <Id>3</Id>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <Desc>three</Desc>
                    </arrayPar>
               </arrayPar>
            </dot:rootPar>
         </mon:request>
      </mon:method1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Because i had to reflect the old wsdl i need to remove:

- request wrapper tag
- arrayPar wrapper tag

Below my classes:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.test.me/method/")]
public interface IMeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<myResponse> method1Async(myRequest request);
}


public class MeService: IMeService
{
    public async Task<myResponse> method1Async(myRequest request)
}


[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "http://www.test.me/method/", WrapperName = "method1")]
public class myRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "rootPar")]
    public rootPar[] rootPar;
}


[DataContract(Namespace ="")]
public class rootPar
{
    [DataMember(Name = "par1")]
    public string par1{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "descPar1")]
    public string descPar1{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="par2")]
    public string par2{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "descPar2")]
    public string descPar2{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public arrPar[] arrPar{ get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace ="")]
public class arrPar
{
    [DataMember(Name="Id")]
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Desc")]
    public string Desc{ get; set; }
}
```

I've tried more and more configuration but i cannot recreate the old wsdl.

Please, any suggestion is appreciated.

Regards

Davide

Comment: Maybe it can helps you to remember that SOAP is still a HTTP communication that you can integrate with any http client and there are a lot of libraries to do the mapping between XML and your models in an easy way. I worked with an old RLC in that way and works better than using the contract

Comment: Maybe you can remove the tag manually and import it using svcutil like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64446120/net-core-3-1-importing-wsdl-errors-how-to-work-around).